# Windows Azure Storage Options For Storing Large Media Files

Tags: azure, storage

I am working to design a windows azure application that will provide online backup storage for very large media files. The application must be capable of storing average 1GB of data for each user. The application must provide random read write access. What will be durable data storage solution for it. Should I use windows azure drive or windows azure page blob storage or any other storage solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do take a look at `Block Blobs` as a storage option for storing your files. `Azure Drive` is simply out of question because it is only accessible from inside a role and only one role instance will have write permission on a drive. All other instances would be able to read from that drive. While `Page Blobs` are meant for random read/write but I don't think (and I may be wrong here) that you would need random read/write access. I guess what you're looking for is a way for the user to update media files and read from media files.

For that, block blobs are your best bet. Each blob is a separate entity so what you could do is create a blob container for each user of your system and have your application save their media files in that container.